# Cannot add web-api controller based on exisiting EF class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a EntityFramework ORM. I try to add a new controller using a wizard;

[image]

and get the following error:

[image]

How can I solve this? I have tried to clean and rebuild, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [`site`](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2011/01/27/the-specified-named-connection-is-either-not-found-in-the-configuration-error/);

> You will get this if you are using Entity Framework and have the
>   edmx/app.config in a seperate place from your main website. The
>   connection information within the app.config file needs to be
>   copied/the same as the connection information contained within the
>   web.config on the root of your website. Set that up and this error
>   will go away.

Also check [Compiler error using EF4 as a separate project than my MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114181/compiler-error-using-ef4-as-a-separate-project-than-my-mvc-project)

Comment: then coping the connection string, and I can leave the EF edmx in my Dal project?

Comment: Just copy your app.config connectionstring and paste your mvc web.config.